# Mongo DB : Querying High Level Structured Collection

Tags: mongodb

This is my  Mongo DB Structure .

```
{
  "_id": "10280",
  "city": "NEW YORK",
  "state": "NY",
  "pop": 5574,
  "loc": [
{
    class: 4
    dept:comp
},
{
    class: 5
    dept:comp

}
{
    class: 5
    dept:comp

}
  ]
}
```

As you seen there is high level and low level associated .

I need to query all the documents if the city is NEW YORK and class is "5"
I am using Java with Mongo DB 
I tried this way

```
 BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        query.put(city, "NEW YORK");
          query.put(class, "5");
```

But its not working . could anybody please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `loc` level of your `class` key and your quotes are messed up.

```java
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("city", "NEW YORK");
query.put("loc.class", 5);
DBObject doc = coll.findOne(query);
```